# How to use a stepper motor and LEDs at the same time?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to make a stepper motor hit a limit switch and then light up 6 LEDs. Individually these all work perfectly fine but when executed all at the same time only the motor works and the LEDs will only flash once when ive not even touched the switch. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Here is the code:

```
// Libaries
#include <ezButton.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

// LED PRE-Setup

int LED[6] = { 2, 5, 4, 6, 12, 13 };

int brightness = 0;
int fadeamount = 5;

// Constants
const float STEPS_PER_REV = 32;
const float GEAR_RED = 64;
const float STEPS_PER_OUT_REV = STEPS_PER_REV * GEAR_RED;
const int blinktime = 500;
int LED_2Interval = 500;
int StepsRequired;
int ledState = LOW;

// Stepper Motor Pre-Setup
Stepper steppermotor(STEPS_PER_REV, 8, 10, 9, 11);

// Switch Pre-Setup
int limitSwitchPin = 7;
// Previous Variables
unsigned long previousLED_2Millis = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;

//==========================

void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(LED[0], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED[1], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED[2], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED[3], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED[4], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED[5], OUTPUT);

    pinMode(ledState, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(limitSwitchPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

    Serial.begin(9600);
}
//==========================

void loop()
{
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    //clockWise();
    updateLEDS();
    switchLEDS();
}

//==========================

void clockWise()
//Turn the stepper motor to hit the limit switch
{
    StepsRequired = -STEPS_PER_OUT_REV / 2;
    steppermotor.setSpeed(1000);
    steppermotor.step(StepsRequired);
    Serial.println("clockWise");
};

void updateLEDS()
//Read the current state of the limit switch to turn the LEDS on or off.
{
    if (digitalRead(limitSwitchPin) == HIGH) {
        ledState = HIGH;
       /* analogWrite(LED, brightness);
        brightness = brightness + fadeamount; ----- Work in progress for a fade feature 
        for (int i = 0; i < 225; i++)

        -fadeamount; */
        Serial.println("LED ON");
    }
    else {
        ledState = LOW;
        Serial.println("LED OFF");
        delay(100);
    }

    if (digitalRead(limitSwitchPin) == HIGH)
        analogWrite(LED, brightness);
    brightness = brightness + fadeamount;
    for (int i = 0; i < 225; i++)
        ;
    -fadeamount;
};
void switchLEDS()
//Turns the LEDS on and off
{

    digitalWrite(LED[0], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[1], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[2], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[3], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[4], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[5], ledState);
};
```

Originally, this was a much shorter code but I read on another post that if I break it into two separate functions "clockWise" and "updateLEDS" that both codes could run at the same time but that hasn't worked.

Comment: `-fadeamount;` is nonsense, that line doesn't do anything.

Comment: I meant to delete all that and move it into the commented part of the if statement, its not the issue anyway.

Comment: Where `clockWise()` is called? Is `Stepper::step()` blocking? If yes, you either should use non-blocking motor control or use interrupts for other tasks. Also `for (int i = 0; i < 225; i++);` do nothing.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to tell if its blocking or not to be honest. And yeah youre right about the for statement, its a work in progress anyway i meant to comment it out before i posted this.

Comment: Why is the step count, for a stepper motor, a floating point value?  Can your system perform 3.14159 steps?  You may have math precision issues using floating point and then converting to or from integers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with the way the updateLEDS() function is designed. The if statement checking the state of the limit switch is repeated twice and the analogWrite(LED, brightness) and brightness for loop are not enclosed inside the first if statement, so it is possible that the LEDs are being turned on and off repeatedly without any delay. Also, it is not clear why you are using a for loop with an empty statement and decrementing the brightness by fadeamount.

Here is a modified version of the updateLEDS() function that should work:

```
void updateLEDS() {
  if (digitalRead(limitSwitchPin) == HIGH) {
    ledState = HIGH;
    analogWrite(LED[0], brightness);
    analogWrite(LED[1], brightness);
    analogWrite(LED[2], brightness);
    analogWrite(LED[3], brightness);
    analogWrite(LED[4], brightness);
    analogWrite(LED[5], brightness);
    brightness = brightness + fadeamount;
    if (brightness >= 255 || brightness <= 0) {
      fadeamount = -fadeamount;
    }
  } else {
    ledState = LOW;
    digitalWrite(LED[0], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[1], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[2], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[3], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[4], ledState);
    digitalWrite(LED[5], ledState);
    brightness = 0;
    fadeamount = 5;
  }
}
```

This should turn on all the LEDs with the same brightness when the limit switch is pressed and gradually increase/decrease the brightness of the LEDs. When the limit switch is released, all the LEDs should turn off immediately. You can adjust the fadeamount variable to change the rate at which the brightness changes.

Also, make sure to call the switchLEDS() function inside the if statement in the updateLEDS() function to turn on/off the LEDs according to the state of the limit switch.